# Titles that designate female leaders

Tags: synonyms, gender-positive

A bit of context: I'm working on a board game and I'm trying to find a title for a (fictional) female leader. It's sci-fantasy, so the title can come from pretty much any culture/era. I'd like to find a word that is not very commonly seen (unlike queen, empress, princess, etc.) and, for thematic reasons, not a feminized version of a male title.

If it were a male character, I'd use something like shogun, archon, czar, etc., but I want something that designates an exclusively female leader...

I tried searching the web, but I couldn't find many that apply to women:

- [Wikipedia – Imperial, royal and noble ranks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperial,_royal_and_noble_ranks)
- [TitleMax – Royal Titles Around The World](https://www.titlemax.com/discovery-center/money-finance/royal-titles-around-the-world/)

I tried getting help in the Worldbuilding exchange (I'm using it to build fiction, after all), but was promptly told off, that it was off-topic, subjective, and that it belongs in History instead. In the History exchange, I was told it was off topic, trying to prove a contentious point, and that it belongs in Culture or Language instead... I don't mean to be a pain or offend anyone, just trying to compile a list of titles that would work in this context.

Comment: Assuming that you're writing for an English speaking audience, why not just make up a title? Any real-world title you might dig up, that fits the criteria, will probably be so obscure (since it doesn't appear in the lists you've already found) that you'd have to explain it in terms of a better known rank anyway.

Comment: I know that [**amazon²**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/amazon) isn't a title or specifically a leader, but many people know its female meaning ... and it's for a game.

Comment: [**Dame**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/dame) is an exclusively female title - not a feminized version of a male title. Or perhaps you could use *actual* names, such as **Cleopatra**, **Boadicea** etc.

Comment: Asking for suggested names is off-topic here too, but Writing.SE have a 'naming' tag. 'Matriarch' has been famously used by E E ('Doc') Smith.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a better fit on Writing.SE, asking for suggested names.

Comment: The best word to use is the word that already means what you are looking for: _Mother_.

Comment: "*… trying to compile a list of titles …*" This site doesn't supply lists. It supplies single answers that are objectively the *right* answer for a given question. If you want a particular title, you have to define what would make it better than the others.